# How to wipe and re-install Kali Linux on an encrypted volume

Tags: boot, kali-linux, usb, grub2

I installed Kali as a single boot on an older macbook. I encrypted the drive. It was great for a while but now 16 months later, I've forgotten the password. There's nothing important on the drive, I just want to wipe it and reinstall.

I've created a new kali linux USB installer (and tried a live version). My problem is a can't load it from grub. I've tried selecting the USB as root and then doing chainloader +1 but it doesn't work (error: invalid EFI file path).

I'd like to just wipe and start fresh. Can you help me out?

Comment: why are you trying to boot the flash drive from grub?

Answer (score 0):

What I would try is:

- Boot up a Linux Live USB
- Install GParted
- See if the disk is listed and delete the partition(s)
- Make a new partition

Hopefully, this helps you!